# Postgres one or the other attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

One or the other attribute. For example:

```
CREATE TYPE example AS(
var1 TEXT,
var2 TEXT);
```

If they have input for var1 they can't have a value for var2.

Answer (score 0):

Use a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE example
   ADD CHECK (val1 IS NULL OR val2 IS NULL);
```

This allows for both columns to be NULL, but you can easily change the condition to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the `CHECK` of your *custom data type* in the table itself:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  txt example,  
  CONSTRAINT one_var_null 
    CHECK (((txt).var1 IS NULL AND (txt).var2 IS NOT NULL) OR
           ((txt).var1 IS NOT NULL AND (txt).var2 IS NULL))
);
```

**EDIT**: much more elegant alternative suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name ([`num_nonnulls`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparison.html))

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  txt example,  
  CONSTRAINT one_var_null 
    CHECK (num_nonnulls((txt).var1, (txt).var2) = 1)
);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e61cf6a76204f7f3524c3b028fcb7dac)